# Order by association field using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Is it possible to write an ActiveRecord query that sorts by an association field if the association exists, and otherwise sorts by an attribute on the object itself?

**Example:** I have a `Discussion` object which `has_many :comments`. I'd like to display a list of discussions sorted by `discussion.latest_comment.created_at`. However, some discussions may not have any comments, in which case I would like use their `discussion.created_at` attribute instead.

The catch is that I need the result to be an `ActiveRecord::Relation` (for performance reasons, and also because we are using Kaminari [which requires a Relation object]).

The only thing I could think of is to actually create a new field like `discussion.latest_comment_at` which would be initially populated by `discussion.created_at` and then updated every time a new comment is posted. However, this doesn't seem very straight-forward from a maintenance perspective (e.g. what happens when a comment gets deleted?).

Comment: Have you tried just doing a joins call to your association then calling order on the joined column first, then order on the local column second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this through SQL, so I cheated and I have my code [set a `last_post_at` attribute whenever a topic is created](https://github.com/radar/forem/blob/master/app/models/forem/post.rb#L116-118).

That way, I can then sort the topics by `last_post_at` rather than having to query two tables at once.

I've seen other forum systems do it this way too, and it seems like what you're designing is exactly a forum-like system.